# Angular 12: InlineSVG not working in production

Tags: angular, svg, webpack, production, inline-svg

I am using Angular 12 with ng-inline-svg. My .svg files are stored in the src/assets folder.

SVG location (TypeScript):

```js
angleIconUrl = '${environment.assetsPath}assets/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg';
```

( The `environment.assetsPath` contains either '/' or 'dashboard/' (dev assets and production assets)

Inline SVG (HTML):

```html
<span class="svg-icon svg-icon-xl" (onSVGFailed)="fail($event)" [inlineSVG]="angleIconUrl"></span>
```

Instead of displaying the provided svg, I get the following error: `No SVG found in loaded contents.`
When I try to use the same angleIconUrl on an img-tag with an src-attribute it works.

I already tried to add the svg files to the assets in my angular.json file but it does not work anyway.

```json
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/.htaccess",
    "src/assets/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg"
],
```

Comment: `assets/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg`?

Answer (score 1):

asset bundle by default are copied to your `/dist` folder and not under `{dist}/assets/` (`dist` varies as per your angular.json config property `outputPath`)

You can either remove the `assets/` from the SVG url or update `angular.json` to have the following

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/.htaccess",
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "/assets/",
        "ignore": ["**/.DS_Store", "**/Thumbs.db", "**/.gitkeep"]
    }
]
```

To test whether it works or not, you can directly type
`http://localhost:4200/assets/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg` (change host and port as per your configuration) into browser address bar. If it loads then your configuration is correct. If not you need to try removing the `assets/` from the path

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Accessing the svg file through the url (http://localhost:4200/assets/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg) already worked before. For some reason its not displayed in the inline-svg. Nevertheless, I tried to edit the assets in the angular.json file according to your answer but unfortunately its not working

Comment: If you are using web-server (nginx, httpd) to host the SVG in prod, check to make sure it is configured correctly. You might want to debug that. http://prod-url/assets/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg should work for inlining scenario to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had shared svg icons stored in the apps/shared/assets/icons/*.
For angular 14 this worked:

in angular.json:

```
"assets":[
...
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "apps/shared/assets/",
      "output": "assets"
    }
]
```

the path to the icon in html:

```
src="assets/icons/connection.svg"
```

and added svg mime type on the server:

```
mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html",
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png",
  ".js" => "text/javascript",
  ".css" => "text/css",
  ".svg" => "image/svg+xml"
)
```